# Generating a number of empty columns efficiently within ActiveAdmin's CSV export

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I wondered if anyone has found an efficient way of generating many empty columns in ActiveAdmin? (The empty columns form part of a requirement of the system importing the CSV).

For reference please see:
http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/4-csv-format.html

```
column("") do |cb|

    empty_columns=',,,,,,,,,,,'

    empty_columns.to_s

end
```

generates

> ",,,,,,,,"

```
column("") do |column|
end
```

generates

> ,

i.e. an empty column with the quote marks.

So I can do one empty column this way, but there's over 30 empty columns, so it doesn't feel efficient to output this with lots of single columns.

I have also tried setting the force_quotes to false within the CSV block.
    csv :options => { :force_quotes => false } do

Any help much appreciated for making this code more maintainable in the future.

Cheers,
Ian.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but based on the documentation you provided, I think you need to invoke `column` once for each column, as in something like:

ActiveAdmin.register Post do
    csv do
      (1..30).each {|i| column "Column#{i}" {""}}
    end
  end

Of course, if the column names don't have to be unique, this could be simplified further.

Comment: Hi Peter, 
Thanks for your comment.
I ended up going with blocks like this interspersed within the data exporting columns.
    50.times do
        column("") do |empty|
 end
    end

Feels like there could be an ActiveAdmin method for empty column, so I added it to their issues list.

Comment: A less verbose, but equivalent way of calling this:

10.times{ column(''){} }